# Сортировка по количеству лайков

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Здравствуйте, вопрос по sql.
Есть 2 таблицы в базе данных. `likes` и `servers`.
Сделал запрос, который должен сортировать записи из `servers` по количеству поставленных им лайков из таблицы `likes` (каждая оценка как отдельная запись в таблице, а не как число).
Всё шикарно работает, кроме момента, когда у записи из `servers` нет ни одной оценки в соответствующей таблице с оценками, эта запись просто не выводится. Я не утверждаю, что следующий код должен и такую запись учитывать, просто я не знаю, как это реализовать, т.к. не силён в sql.

Вот запрос (за форматирование самого запроса не волнуйтесь, я использую ORM и он требует подобного синтаксиса):

`select s.id, l.target, count(*) as marks from servers s inner join likes l on l.target = s.id group by s.id order by marks`

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Замените внутреннее связывание на левое.

Comment: `ORDER BY marks DESC` или `ASC` - где `DESC` - от большего к меньшему, а `ASC` от меньшего к большему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую попробовать вот так:

```
select s.id, count(l.id) as marks from servers s left join likes l on l.target = s.id group by s.id order by marks
```

Обратите внимание на несколько моментов:

1. `left join` - он возьмёт все записи из servers.
2. у вас `group by s.id` но в списке полей есть ещё `l.target` не под агрегатной функцией - так нельзя, `l.target` не нужен.
3. `count(*)` в вашем случае (с `inner join`) нормально посчитает, но с `left join` посчитает и те записи из servers для которых не нашлось лайков, поэтому с `left join` нужно `count(l.id)` или `count(l.target)` если в likes нет поля id.